# apt-get update gives bzip2 error on fresh Ubuntu 12.04(LTS) in Virtual Box version 4.2.18

Tags: 12.04, apt, virtualbox, bzip2

A fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04(LTS) onto Virtual Box 4.2.18 seems to go well, however, I receive a bzip2 related error when trying to update.  I was hoping a seasoned Ubuntu expert could help me decipher and correct the problem.  Here is the terminal output:

---

```
adam@adamVB:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for adam: 
Hit http:// extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Get:1 http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]
Hit http:// extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                   
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http:// extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                     
Get:2 http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB]
Hit http:// extras.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http:// extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http:// extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Get:3 http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]         
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg                 
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                               
Get:4 http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [102 kB]        
Ign http: // extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US                   
Get:5 http: // us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]          
Ign http: // extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                       
Hit http: //us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                    
Hit http: //us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                          
Get:6 http: //security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [2,494 B]
Get:7 http: //us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources [5,470 B]
100% [7 Sources bzip2 10.0 kB] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]
bzip2: Data integrity error when decompressing.
    Input file = (stdin), output file = (stdout)

It is possible that the compressed file(s) have become corrupted.
You can use the -tvv option to test integrity of such files.

You can use the `bzip2recover' program to attempt to recover
data from undamaged sections of corrupted files.

Get:8 http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [30.9 kB]
100% [8 Sources bzip2 0 B] [Waiting for headers] [Connecting to security.ubuntu
bzip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly;
    perhaps it is corrupted?  *Possible* reason follows.
bzip2: Inappropriate ioctl for device
    Input file = (stdin), output file = (stdout)

It is possible that the compressed file(s) have become corrupted.
You can use the -tvv option to test integrity of such files.

You can use the `bzip2recover' program to attempt to recover
data from undamaged sections of corrupted files.

Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                      
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                    
Get:9 http: //security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [1,797 B]
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages
Get:10 http: //security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages [376 kB]
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
Hit http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages      
Get:11 http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages [91.8 kB]
Get:12 http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [2,439 B]
Get:13 http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [402 kB] 
Get:14 http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [4,620 B]
Get:15 http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [96.5 kB]
Get:16 http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2,649 B]
Hit http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex          
Hit http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex    
Hit http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex    
Hit http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex      
Get:17 http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages [454 kB]  
Hit http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en            
Hit http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http:// security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en        
Get:18 http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages [105 kB]    
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages              
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                 
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Get:19 http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [454 kB]
Get:20 http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [8,028 B]
Get:21 http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [105 kB]  
Get:22 http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources [8,909 B]
Get:23 http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages [763 kB]
Get:24 http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [12.2 kB]
Get:25 http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages [238 kB]
Get:26 http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [15.3 kB]
Get:27 http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [787 kB]
Get:28 http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [12.2 kB]
Get:29 http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [243 kB]
Get:30 http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [15.4 kB]
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex         
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex   
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex   
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex     
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources                
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources          
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources            
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources          
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main amd64 Packages         
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages   
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages     
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages   
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages          
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages    
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages      
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages    
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex       
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex 
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex 
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex   
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                   
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en             
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en             
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en               
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en           
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en     
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en     
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en       
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en         
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en   
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en   
Hit http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en     
Err http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Fetched 4,432 kB in 2min 31s (29.3 kB/s)                                       
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_universe_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_restricted_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
adam@adamVB:~$
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it worked for me:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```